# Strange path of new file in Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I add a new file in normal way using 'File > New > File' in the project the file path in the project is set with strange prefix. In the `pbxproj` file:

```
B28A19422E8761000F9E8AC /* File.swift */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.swift; name = File.swift; path = "../../../../../../../../../System/Volumes/Data/Users/<USER>/Documents/work/<Project>/File.swift"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

So, it leads to crash while building on another Mac.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found, simple drag and drop of the file works after removing reference and returning the file back to the project. You shouldn't use 'Copy items if needed'. It seems, this is Xcode bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using absolute path to your project files.

Try marking the `Copy items if needed` option when adding the files. It should solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Hello. It doesn't matter, relative path or other type is used. For each case I can see such prefix ../../../System/ .